# What does the term "kernel" in "reproducing kernel Hilbert space" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Where did this terminology origin from?
Can you illustrate the meaning of "kernel" with a simple example? Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) for the definition.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the history, but this terminology probably comes from the kernel of an [integral operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), not from the kernel of a homomorphism.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24098/what-does-kernel-mean-in-integral-kernel